# Codeigniter base_url in plesk

Tags: php, codeigniter, plesk, base-url

Recently I uploaded a website which created using codeigniter framework into plesk. Inside the c-panal I changed the document root into httpdocs/public_html/cliftonhotel.ae, and I uploaded the files using FTP into the same. I changed the base_url into

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://cliftonhotel.ae/';
```

The problem is if I enter the web address it loads fine(The home page), but the other menus are not working, they shows a 404 page not found error.

[http://cliftonhotel.ae/][1] 
this is the site. What is the solution, thankyou.

Comment: use base_url or site_url in links for the menu can solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the links you have created are missing index.php

For example: http://cliftonhotel.ae/index.php/home/about works

but http://cliftonhotel.ae/home/about does not.

So you have to either change the links or edit your .htaccess for url rewriting

Comment: Thank you for you reply, but i didn't declare index.php anywhere, then why its coming like this, editing my .htaccess means remove the index.php portion???

Comment: You do not need to declare index.php in codeigniter. It is its default behaviour. To override this behaviour, you need to do url rewriting in .htacces file. If you are new to this, its best to leave it untouched

Answer (score 1):

Do some changes, hope it's work
// .htaccess file

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

// config.php

```
    $config['index_page'] = ' ';
```